# I don't know how to fix this error code :Error: the function does not take 5 arguments and Error: too few arguments in function call.

Tags: visual-c++

```
// Description: This program calculates the average of a group of five test scores where the group is dropped.

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getScore(double);
void findLowest(double, double, double, double, double, double);
void calcAverage(double, double, double, double, double, double);



int main()
{
    double ix, iy, iz, iw, ib;


    getScore(ix);
    getScore(iy);
    getScore(iz);
    getScore(iw);
    getScore(ib);

    calcAverage(ix, iy, iz, iw, ib);

    return 0;
}

void getScore(double score)
{
    cout << "What is your score?";
    cin >> score;
    if (score < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error";
        exit(0);
    }
}

void findLowest(double ba, double bb, double bc, double bd, double be, double exclude)
{
    if (ba < bb && ba < bc && ba < bd && ba < be)
        exclude = ba;
    else if (bb < ba && bb < bc && bb < bd & bb < be)
        exclude = bb;
    else if (bc < ba && bc < bb && bc < bd && bc < be)
        exclude = bc;
    else if (bd < ba && bd < bb && bd < bc && bd < be)
        exclude = bd;
    else
        exclude = be;

}

void calcAverage(double aa, double ab, double ac, double ad, double ae, double drop)
{
    double average;
    findLowest(aa, ab, ac, ad, ae, drop);
    average = (aa + ab + ac + ad + ae - drop) / 4;
    cout << "The test score we are dropping is " << drop << endl;
    cout << "Your average is " << average << endl;
}
```

it says that i dont have enough arguments in line 35 (calcAverage in int main) and when i put another variable in, it says that all my i's in main are no longer initialized. I'm super confused and lost about why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

You Pass 5 arguments from calling , but calcaverage take 6 argument, right !

Comment: I've been trying to ad the variable ir with it and then it tells me: "uninitialized local variable "ix"" line 29 and im not sure what that is about either

Answer (score 1):

The function prototype for `calcAverage()` is this:

```
void calcAverage(double, double, double, double, double, double);
//Note 6 arguments.
```

You call it like this:

```
calcAverage(ix, iy, iz, iw, ib); //Note 5 arguments
```

Therefore, the compiler is complaining about less arguments than expected.
In addition, all these variables:

```
double ix, iy, iz, iw, ib;
```

All these variables are not initialized, and therefore, undefined values are being passed to the function. They could be any values between the minimum double and maximum double range.